# Importing an *.ics/Calendar event into a blackberry calendar

Tags: php, blackberry, calendar, icalendar

I'm creating an ics calendar event/appointment in PHP.  After creating the event, it's made available for download and import via hyperlink:

```
     $icsFilename=sprintf("calTruthUniversal%dFile.ics",$randNum);

     $fp = fopen($icsFilename, 'w');
     fwrite($fp, 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR'."\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "PRODID:-//Truth Universal, LLC//Truth Universal Calendar 70.9054//EN\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "VERSION:2.0\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "DTSTART:".$dtstart."\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "DTEND:".$dtend."\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "ORGANIZER;CN=truthuniversal@yahoo.com:mailto:truthuniversal@yahoo.com\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "DESCRIPTION:".$description."\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "LOCATION:".$c_address."\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "SUMMARY:".$c_event."\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "END:VEVENT\r\n");
     fwrite($fp, "END:VCALENDAR\r\n");
     fclose($fp);
      //echo "<br>";
      //echo "<hr>";

     echo"<a href=\"download.php?icsFile=".$icsFilename."\"><img src=\"../images/icon_cal.png\" border=\"0\"></a><br><br>";
```

The script download.php sets the headers/content-type and streams the file for download:

```
      <?php

      $myFile = $_GET['icsFile'];

      $size=filesize($myFile);

      header("Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=".$myFile);
      header("Content-Length: ".$size);
      header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

      $fh = @fopen($myFile, 'rb');
      $theData = fread($fh, $size);
      fclose($fh);

      echo $theData;
      ?>
```

When the ics file is downloaded via hyperlink on iPhone and Android phones, it is imported into the phones' calendars.  Blackberry however, does not do this.  It downloads the file, but only after displaying this alert:  "The item you selected cannot be displayed.  Do you wish to save the item?"  It is not importing the file into the calendar.

I've even experimented with changing the Content-Type to "application/x-rimcalendarevent" but to no avail.

Does anyone have a solution?!?

Frustrated,

Ujasiri

Comment: Nice code. I especially like how you're allowing a malicious user to steal **ANY** file on your server for which they know the path name. I hope you like your `/etc/passwd` file floating around the interwebitubes.

Comment: @MarcB What are you talking about?  Do yo have my /etc/passwd file?  Is this how you've you gotten your reputation, by being a code snob?  I didn't ask you for a code critique.  If you don't have the answer, please don't waste my time.

Comment: No, but I'm saying that if you put this code into production, remote users can use it to download ANY file on your server. Consider it a warning that you're writing highly insecure code.

Comment: @MarcB  OK, THAT I can appreciate.  You can keep the sarcasm.  Do you have any suggestions?  And how could they get to ANY file on the server if I have something like 400 as the permission mode on my subdirectories?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
 What I did is I generated an event with blackberry and sent it back to me. This way I had a "correct" file. I found was several differences, but the one that solved the problem was the end of the file. I had to add two or three more empty lines to the end of ics file.

Something like:

```
fwrite($fp, "END:VCALENDAR\r\n");
fwrite($fp, "\r\n\r\n\r\n");
fclose(4fp);
```

Worked for me.

Good luck!